# Datacontext into ListView --- Windows Store Aplication

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

in my Application i have a datacontext into page, but, i want to move this datacontext to ListView, because i need to create more datacontext.

I tried to assign a name to call the DataContext grid, but doesn't work...

```
<Page
x:Class="Food_UsuarioWin8.Pages.HUB"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Food_UsuarioWin8.Pages"
xmlns:vmSegments="using:Food_UsuarioWin8.ViewModels"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

 </Page.Resources>
<Page.DataContext>
    <vmSegments:ViewModelSegments x:Name="DataContextSegments"/>
</Page.DataContext>

 <ListView x:Name="ListViewSegments" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" DataContext="{StaticResource DataContextSegments}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewSItemtyleECFood}" >
  <Viewbox>
  </Viewbox>
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can create a "composite" data context.

My preference is a single `ViewModel` class with properties for each data context you need:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Segments = new ViewModelSegments();
        SomethingElse = new ViewModelSomethingElse();
    }

    public ViewModelSegments Segments { get; set; }
    public ViewModelSomethingElse SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

In XAML you set your main `ViewModel` as `DataContext` for the page and then bind individual controls to its properties:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Segments}" />
```

Alternatively you can put individual data context classes into resources and use them from there:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelSegments x:Key="DataContextSegments" />
    <vm:ViewModelSomethingElse x:Key="DataContextSomethingElse" />
</Page.Resources>

<ListView DataContext="{StaticResource DataContextSegments}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: exactly, I put a name to viemodel (class)DataContextSegments and then assigned to the ListView's DataContext, but doesn't work. look at my xaml. i want to do without c#, just xaml.

Comment: in this line code <vm:ViewModelSegments x:Key="DataContextSegments" /> i can't put Key, just (FieldModifier, Name, Uid)!

Comment: @Makito What do you mean by not being able to add `x:Key`? You need to give a key to a resource to access it, you can't reference it by name. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) is a nice introduction to resources in XAML. Although it is for WPF, WinRT is not all that different in this case.

Comment: no, no, I know it's the "x: Key =" Name "" (I know xaml), but I can not assign the key, because it does not recognize it, I only see the options Name, FieldModifier, Uid

Comment: Have developed for Windows8? ... I am inside a page, and before any definition of grid or any other, I put <page.Resources> <vm:ViewModelSegments x:name="DataContextSegments" /> </ page.Resources>, but I can not put "key "because it does not exist in this context

Comment: @Makito I've done lots Windows Store development and I know it's quite different form WPF. But trust me, `Resources` work just the same. I don't know why `x:Key` wouldn't be available in your context. Maybe it would help if I saw the complete page. [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10676122/App20.zip) you can download a small working sample proving that my code above works.